# Parsing JSON Object Through Activities

Tags: android, json

I have an activity which currently displays a list of Bars from google  API working fine, I am trying to get it so that the "name" and other details are parsed through with the onclick. currently it opens a new activity but i cannot get the parsed JSON which i sent with putExtra.
Any help Appreciated.

Bars.java

```
public class Bars extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = Bars.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
     ListView lv;

    // URL to get Results JSON
    private static String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.785091,-73.968285&radius=1000&type=restaurant,bar,food,point_of_interest&keyword=bar&opennow=true&key=MYAPICODE";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultsList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bars);

        resultsList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        new Getresults().execute();
    }

    //Async task class to get json by making HTTP call

    private class Getresults extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Bars.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpConnect sh = new HttpConnect();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

                    // looping through All results
                    for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = results.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        String vicinity = c.getString("vicinity");
                        String rating = c.getString("rating");




                        // tmp hash map for single resu
                        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        result.put("name", name);
                        result.put("vicinity", vicinity);
                        result.put("rating", rating) ;

                        // adding result to result list
                        resultsList.add(result);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Bars.this, resultsList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "vicinity",
                    "rating" }, new int[]{name,
                    R.id.vicinity, R.id.rating});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            // on lick listener to send name position
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Intent newActivity = new Intent(Bars.this, 
                    SecondActivity.class);
                    newActivity.putExtra("position", position);
                    newActivity.putExtra("name", name);

                    startActivity(newActivity);


                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see the final part sends the "name" and "position" to the secondActivity Class which is as follows

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String name;
    Intent getName;
    Bundle extras;

    TextView name1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

        getName = this.getIntent();
        extras = getName.getExtras();


       // Intent intent = getIntent();
      //  String name = intent.getStringExtra( name: "name");






    }
    public void name(View view){
        name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);

       getIntent().getStringExtra("name");


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you have initialized name. But I can see in your `onPostexecute` block you have written this code

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Bars.this, resultsList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "vicinity",
                "rating" }, new int[]{name,
                R.id.vicinity, R.id.rating});
```

In the above code you have mentioned `name` as `int`. See this line.

```
int[]{name,R.id.vicinity, R.id.rating});
```

So you cant get value of name by calling  `intent.getStringExtra('name')` in your second activity.

Comment: Okay, so you know how i would get it in my second activity? or if there is a way of mentioning it that it is not int

Comment: Get the hashmap by resultList.get(selectedPosition). Then send it to second activity

Comment: Thank you will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You'll need access to the adapter from adapterView, then get your hashMap by position and pull the item

```
@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    ListAdapter adapter = (ListAdapter) adapterView.getAdapter()
    HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) adapter.getItem(position)
    String name = map.get("name") // may be a null

    Intent newActivity = new Intent(Bars.this, SecondActivity.class);
    newActivity.putExtra("position", position);
    newActivity.putExtra("name", name);
    startActivity(newActivity);
}
```